# How can I return click again after disabling it?

Tags: jquery, onclick, bind, unbind

How can I return click again after disabling it?

For instance, when the page is loaded I want to turn off all clickable button on the menu,

```
$(".menu > ul > li > a").click(function(){return false;});
```

after 3 seconds later, I want to turn them back on, so I am doing this,

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
     $(".menu > ul > li > a").click(function(){return true;});
}, 3000 );
```

it does not work of course! How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would be better off binding and unbinding the event handler

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

```
var handler = function() {
    return false;
};
$(".menu > ul > li > a").bind('click', handler);
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $(".menu > ul > li > a").unbind('click', handler);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried out

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
 $(".menu > ul > li > a").unbind('click').click(function(){return true;});
}, 3000 );
```